# Whats with all the bad image links today?

Tags: support, status-norepro, images

Since last night, I've encountered a surprising number of posts on superuser with image links that say "Enter image Description Here", and which fail to resolve to a page on Imgur (Connection reset error).

Whats going on?

Here is one current example (hopefully its not fixed before you look at it).

[How to prevent McAfee LiveSafe from installing uTorrent on my system?](https://superuser.com/questions/1045564/how-to-prevent-mcafee-livesafe-from-installing-utorrent-on-my-system)

Edit, the page linked in my example has been "fixed" and I now see the images inline in the Op post.

Comment: Works on my machine... Imgur having momentary problems?

Comment: It is possible but I've noticed it on multiple machines from multiple ISP connections, on at least 8 different posts. First noticed issue last night, and it has continued into the day. If theres no problem for anyone else, then theres no problem, but that would defy any rational explanation I can come up with.

Comment: My guess would be imgur issues. Works for me. The next time this sorta thing happens I suspect a screenshot might be useful.

Comment: Might be a firewall or antivirus product common to all the machines you've tested. ENOREPRO (can't reproduce).

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you all for your comments.